# Does the install of .NET 4.6.2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 require a restart?

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

We want to install .NET Framework 4.6.2 on our Windows Server 2012 R2.
We have the .exe and put it in a .cmd script.

We took a snapshot and installed it using the script. Sometimes we got the message to restart the server and sometimes it didn't appear.

It seems to appear when our Powershell console is also opened? When everything is closed it does nog give us the message to restart. What is the reason for this and do we still need to restart?

Because we are scripting a whole installation procedure it wouldn't be recommended for us to perform restarts.

Comment: Just delay the restart until you've finished? As PowerShell is capable to use .NET and uses it internally it's likely holding some references. So files can not be updated and will only get updated after a restart.

Comment: I'm afraid some things are dependent of the .NET part so a restart needs to happen earlier. Thanks for your info.

Comment: About the "what is the reason for this?", you can use SysInternals' PendMoves utility to get a list of pending changes that will be done after reboot. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2):

Net 4.6.2 Change many things on system, so restart will be needed anyway. Just suppress reboot /norestart /q , do all needed task inside your task sequence and reboot system on the end of task.